# redirect after process php

Tags: ajax, forms

well after reading all the related topics still no success,

I have 4 files **index.php** with a simple form, after submit I use **process.php** to send back (ajax) errors to index.php using  external **script.js** file and also send mail to the owner of this site,all i need is that the user will also be redirected to a **thank-you.html** page (if there are no errors of course) but no luck ,I have tried all the combinations suggested:

```
 header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/thank-you.html");

  header("Location:thank-you.html");

    if (success).....
    echo
   <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      window.location = "http://www.website.com/thank-you.html";
      //-->
      </script>
```

I have tried to put it in the bottom of the process,php ,also in the top of the page also tried to put in the script.js-inside `$ajax` function but nothing:(((

Can anyone tell me what to do?

**solved:**

thank you all so much:)))))  it should be inside the ajax function in the script , right after success: function(data){ I have placed it in the bottom of the script and it didnt work before but now its perfect!

Comment: you're saying this is ajax so php cannot redirect it is just getting a response from the server, so at the place of trying to redirect in the php, let it return something to the javascript function like echo 'success'; then in the javascript function test the response and if it is success, use `window.location = "http://www.website.com/thank-you.html";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this inside of a jQuery $.ajax() call, use the "success" method instead.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        //etc...
        success: function(){
            window.location.href="thank-you.html"
        }
    });
```

The correct usage in JS is "window.location.href".

Also, a PHP file with "header" being set during an AJAX call won't redirect the client browser.

Comment: thank you:) why sending the header didnt work ?even when putting it before all the other output?

Comment: PHP's "header" function will work on client-loaded pages. So if you went to www.mytest.com/header.php in your browser, it would redirect you to whatever page you wanted it to. But when a page is loaded through an AJAX call, it's not fired through the client browser, so it processes the header for the script calling it, not the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will need to handle the redirect once you get the response from **process.php** IE: in the **success** callback.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function () {
        window.location.href = 'thank-you.html';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo '
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  window.location = "http://www.website.com/thank-you.html";
  //-->
  </script>';
```

assuming that is from php you were missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I handled it a little differently as I handled something similar recently. I have the PHP page echo back "true" (this could also just be an INT) and then run if/else statements in the ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            url : "process.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : formData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if (data == "true")
                {
                window.location = "http://www.website.com/thank-you.html";}
            }
```